# Use Series to Compute $\int_{0}^{1}xcosxdx$ correct to three decimal places.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this homework problem and I'm a little confused as to how to complete this.

"Use Series to Compute $\int_0^1 x \cos x \,dx$ correct to three decimal places."

(1) My first intuition is to plug it into a series, so $\sum_{0}^{1}x \cos x$.

(2) Then I think I would create a partial sum, so $S_1 = S_0 + S_1$

(3) Which then gives me 0 + 0, which is 0 and does not have any decimal places.

So I'm clearly doing something wrong, if anyone can elaborate and point me in the right direction that would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\cos{x}$?

Comment: how would you define $\sum_0^1 x\cos x$?

Comment: I learned Taylor Series, I'm pretty awful at it though. But thanks for the tip, I think I know where you're leading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means to use the Maclaurin series expansion of the cosine function
$$\cos{(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\dots$$
So by taking the first three terms for example, the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 x\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}\right) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{55}{144}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I do see how that works out. (: